# How to use Jenkins certificate credentials binding for curl request?

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to authenticate to puppet master to delete host key in a Jenkins pipeline. I have the certificate, private key and CA certificate for puppet master which I can convert into PFX(or PKCS12) format. However, I am at loss as to how I can use the certificate credentials binding in a curl request within the pipeline. It would be great if someone could shed some light in this.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an option in credential management section of your Jenkins job to have an environment variable set for this.

Lets say you set it to $CERT

When your job is running the variable would contain the path to the file so you  could just include it in your curl command with the right options.

`curl  --cacert $CERT https://url`

For more info:

the subject in general and how jenkins approaches it 
    https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

an example of how this works. 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs -

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate a bit more? In credential management section, an ID is generated for the certificate uploaded in PKCS#12 format. Do you mean to set CERT to this ID? I guess we need to use withCredentials for using the certificate credentials binding.

Comment: yes , if upload the cert to the jenkins credential management system it will safely provide it to your jobs using the mechanism above. I'll add a documentation link